# Pivot wider without getting duplicates, and use bind_rows without losing column name info

Tags: r, pivot, bind

I need to transform a dataframe in R in a certain manner, and the only solution I have so far found is using a for loop (which is not very elegant). There must be a way to do this with dplyr::bind_rows or tidyr::pivot_longer, but so far no one was able to help me. Is there an R expert that has an idea?

Here's where I fail so far:

```
#get all x data into one column
df.trial <-  data.frame(x1 = seq(10), 
                        y1 = runif(10),
                        x2 = seq(11,20),
                        y2 = runif(10))

#this is the shape I want - but not only for the first 2 columns
#works, but only for two columns > requires loop
df.trial %>% dplyr::select(c(1,2))%>%
  tidyr::pivot_longer(cols = 2, values_to = 'Y', names_to = 'NAME')

#produces double and quadruple entries
df.trial %>%
  tidyr::pivot_longer(cols = c(1,3), values_to = 'X', names_to = 'NAMEX')%>%
  tidyr::pivot_longer(cols = c(1,2), values_to = 'Y', names_to = 'NAME')
  
col_names <- c("x", "y")
df.1 <- select(df.trial, ends_with("1")) %>% rename(x = starts_with('x'))
df.2 <- select(df.trial, ends_with("2")) %>% rename(x = starts_with('x'))
#produces double entries
bind_rows(df.1, df.2)%>%
  tidyr::pivot_longer(!1, names_to = 'NAME', values_to = 'Y')
```

[Descriptive Image: consecutive x and y pairs for different properties, labelled 'property.x', 'property.y' are transformed to a long dataframe with x, y and the property name](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YMpgl.png)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do it in a more elegant way than using a `for` loop, you can use `purrr::map_dfr` that automatically returns one data.frame:

```r
library(purrr)
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)

set.seed(4)
df.trial <-  data.frame(x1 = seq(10), 
                        y1 = runif(10),
                        x2 = seq(11,20),
                        y2 = runif(10))

suffixes <- c("1", "2")

suffixes %>% 
  map_dfr(
    function(suffix) {
      df.trial %>% 
        select(ends_with(suffix)) %>% 
        rename(x = starts_with("x"),
               NAME = starts_with("y"))
    }
  )
#>     x        NAME
#> 1   1 0.585800305
#> 2   2 0.008945796
#> 3   3 0.293739612
#> 4   4 0.277374958
#> 5   5 0.813574215
#> 6   6 0.260427771
#> 7   7 0.724405893
#> 8   8 0.906092151
#> 9   9 0.949040221
#> 10 10 0.073144469
#> 11 11 0.754675027
#> 12 12 0.286000621
#> 13 13 0.100053522
#> 14 14 0.954068775
#> 15 15 0.415607119
#> 16 16 0.455102418
#> 17 17 0.971055656
#> 18 18 0.583987980
#> 19 19 0.962204624
#> 20 20 0.761702403
```

<sup>Created on 2021-11-02 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v1.0.0)</sup>

Comment: Thank you! Does this also work when I do not know the column names, i.e. I only know that everything goes into the 'Property' column? From your code it looks as though this only works for known pairs of column names. If you have a look at my example, the property could also be something very different, for example names ect.

Comment: No, it does not work completely automatically, but you could use code to determine the names you need to know. What do you mean by Property column? Please provide an example previous format/expected outcome in code and not as an image

Comment: Hm yeah, but then I'm running into for loops again. The format is exactly as I provided, with property I was referring to the 'NAME' - in this case I want to write '1' or '2' to NAME, but this could also be 'elephant', 'penguin' and 'mouse', ect. For very wide dataframes wirting these up gets very extensive. I think the takeaway so far is that since this is not a 'true' wide dataframe, R does not support its transformation to a long dataframe.